# A map command not working correctly in Vim

Tags: vimrc

`imap` command does not work for me as expected in Vim. I place

```
inoremap <F2> abcde
```

in my `.vimrc` file, but when I press the `F2` button in the insert mode, all I get is the `<F2>` symbol appearing in the text file, just as typed here, with brackets.

Testing it with `:verbose imap <F2>?` gives

```
i  <F2>        * abcde<Space>
```

At the same time I have a mapping for the `normal` mode  in Vim:

```
nnoremap <F2> i\[<CR><CR>\] <Esc>ki<Space><Space>
```

and it works just as expected! (I use it to type multi-line formulas in LaTeX, `\[ \]`).

Since the mapping works in the `normal` mode, I do not think that this is the problem with unusual interpretation of the function keys on in my terminal.

Substituting `F2` with `F3`, `F4`, etc does not help.

Tested: xfce4-terminal; plain xterm; console. System: Linux Mint.

Would appreciate your help very much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if it happens with `vim -Nu NONE`.

I suspect that you have `set paste` in your configuration.

If it is, unset it and check if your mapping would work.

Excerpt from `:h 'paste'`

```
'paste'         boolean (default off)
                global
    Put Vim in Paste mode.
    ...
    When the 'paste' option is switched on (also when it was already on):
        - mapping in Insert mode and Command-line mode is disabled
        - abbreviations are disabled
        - 'autoindent' is reset
        - 'expandtab' is reset
        - 'hkmap' is reset
        - 'revins' is reset
        - 'ruler' is reset
        - 'showmatch' is reset
        - 'smarttab' is reset
        - 'softtabstop' is set to 0
        - 'textwidth' is set to 0
        - 'wrapmargin' is set to 0
        - 'varsofttabstop' is made empty
    These options keep their value, but their effect is disabled:
        - 'cindent'
        - 'formatoptions' is used like it is empty
        - 'indentexpr'
        - 'lisp'
        - 'smartindent'
    .....
```

Comment: Maxim, thank you so so much!!!!!! I spend hours and hours on this... I should have asked earlier...

Comment: 2nd update: Ultisnips and vim-snippets started working, finally!! I gave up years ago... (Completion was not working, which is in insert mode, too) -- Thank you so much  again!!